# PHP session error

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-state, session-variables

I am using following session variables on 3 pages:-

On Login page,

```
$_SESSION['login']=1;
```

On Logout page,

```
unset($_SESSION['login']);
```

On Home page,

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
header("location: index.php");
exit();
 }
```

My homepage is not redirecting to the index.php after vising Logout page.

Comment: Do you have a redirect in your logout page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you call `session_start()` at the top of the Logout page?